# Re-using bedika cloths

Tags: halacha, niddah

Nowadays it is common for women to use 'one-time' disposable bedika cloths. Can these be laundered for reuse? My reason to think that this may not be possible is simply because I have never heard of the practice to do this. Furthermore, it could be more reasonable to assume that women in the past did launder their bedika cloths due to possible lack of availability in more remote places.

Comment: Do you mean halachicaly is it permissible to launder dirty cloths for use in bedikot, or has anyone tried laundering the common disposable bedika cloths and did they hold up enough for reuse?

Comment: I highly doubt you'd be able to reuse one of the disposable bedika cloths after getting it completely wet.

Comment: @Daniel Funny :-o. I know the question is phrased poorly. I think by "these" the OP meant to exclude the word "disposable".

Comment: @DanF What do you mean? The OP specifically mentions the disposable ones.

Comment: @Daniel On re-reading this, you may have a point. I'm speaking out of ignorance, here. Somehow, between your comment and the word "disposable", I think of these "cloths" being like "Pampers". I've never seen a disposable bedika cloth. Perhaps, they CAN physically be laundered and dried? I think OP may want to include a link or brief description to clarify its physical properties.

Comment: @DanF In my experience, they're always made out of 100% cotton and quite thin. I've never tried, but I imagine putting them in water would have a similar effect to putting a cotton ball in water. Obviously my wife spends much more time handling them than I do, though.

Comment: @Daniel I guess your wife can always add a comment, here, to clarify things :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Halacha spoke if the cloth (witness) is baduk (verified as without spot) before the bedika, I never see a need for (or an halachical concept of) new cloth.

See Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea [196, 6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5540)

For source Gemara Nidda 17a:

> Come and hear: And the people of the house of Monobaz did three things, and on account of these they were honourably mentioned: T... they examined their beds with cotton {following the first French translation in Rashi's comment, and in a second explanation Rashi said white clean whool}, ... They examined their beds with cotton {according to Rashi}.' This provides support for a ruling of Samuel. For Samuel ruled: The bed(31) may be examined only with cotton tufts or with clean and soft wool. Rab observed: This explains what they said in Palestine on Sabbath eves, when I was there, 'Who requires cotton {according to Rashi} tufts for his bread', and I did not understand at the time what they meant. Raba stated: **Old {whiter than the news, Rashi} flax** garments are admirably suited for examination purposes. But can this be correct, seeing that the school of Manasseh taught: The bed **may not be examined either with a red rag or with a black one or with flax**, but only with cotton tufts or with clean and soft wool? This is no difficulty, since the latter refers to flax while the former refers to garments of flax. And if you prefer I might reply: Both ref to garments of flax but the latter deals with new ones while the former deals with old ones.

#### `Can these be laundered for reuse?`

### Yes.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73241/re-using-bedika-cloths#comment213193_73241; I don't understand this question to be asking whether it's ok to launder cloths in general to re-use them for _bedikot_. I understand it to be asking if it's **possible** to launder and re-use disposable _bedikah_ cloths.

Comment: @Daniel why not. Remember that some Edim are not realy spotted after Bedika. Anyway you can try and following the result decide if the Ed is white and Baduk

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you just wrote.

Comment: @Daniel After washing you can simply look if the cloth is white and clean, if it is, so this is a good cloth for bedika.

Comment: Is the mishnah in Nidah 62 relevant? See the [Daf Yomi Digest](http://www.dafdigest.org/Nidah/Niddah%20062.pdf) it tells how to test between red dye and blood by using seven substances in order.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I am not sure but I remember that this is a diagnostic test to verify the composition of the spot

Comment: @kouty But after washing a disposable _bedikah_ cloth, it will probably be wet and soggy and unsuitable to ever be used again.

Comment: @Daniel the best method is experimental method.